# Anorexia and drinking water

Tags: anorexia

I would like to know whether anorexic people have trouble with drinking water as well or just solid food.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: No.

However, A number of psychological factors contribute to Anorexia nervosa and some patients might also have issues with water intake.

It is interesting to note that Anorexia nervosa is stongly related to impaired water metabolism (water balance in other words), at times (rarely) leading to water intoxication and even death.

---

[Fluid intake, personality and behaviour in patients with eating disorders, Abraham, S.F., Hart, S., Luscombe, G. et al. Eat Weight Disord (2006) 11: e30. doi:10.1007/BF03327750](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBF03327750)

[Hart, S., Abraham, S., Franklin, R. C. and Russell, J. (2011), The reasons why eating disorder patients drink. Eur. Eat. Disorders Rev., 19: 121–128. doi:10.1002/erv.1051](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/erv.1051/full)

[Paul Jacquin, Olivier Ouvry, Patrick Alvin, Fatal water intoxication in a young patient with anorexia nervosa, Journal of Adolescent Health, Volume 13, Issue 7, 1992, Pages 631-633, ISSN 1054-139X, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/1054-139X(92)90379-P.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/1054-139X(92)90379-P)